# How to prove the disease rate in conditional probability

Tags: probability

recently I am confused by a question.

Suppose screening test A has been used to detect disease D. Based on historical performance, it's known that 21% of patients who are A positive will have disease D, while 99% of patients who are A negative will NOT have disease D. It is known that 20% of the population are detected to be A positive.

I would like to show that the rate of disease D in the population is 5.00%.

P(Disease D | A positive) = 21%
P(No Disease D | A negative) = 99%
P(A positive) = 20%

P(Disease D | A positive) = P(A positive | Disease D) * P( Disease D) / P( A positive)

However, P(A positive | Disease D) is unknown, how can I prove this question?
Thank you very much

Comment: Say  there were $N$ people.  How many are $A$ positive?  How many of those have the disease?   How many are $A$ negative?  How many of those have the disease?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have that by [LOTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability)

$$P(D)=P(D|A^+)P(A^+)+P(D|A^-)P(A^-)=0.21\cdot 0.20+0.01\cdot 0.80=0.05$$